# What jquery slideshow can I use to cycle through and highlight images?

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, slideshow, photo

I'm looking for a Jquery gallery/slideshow that cycles through/highlights these photos: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cagg3820.

The name will appear on active image and their will be no full-size image, maybe just option of linking each thumbnail to a url/page.

Has anyone used or come across any galleries that come close that I can modify or work from as a base?

Thanks!

Comment: you could always write your own jquery/javascript to do what you need - seems like that is not even a thought to some people now a days

Comment: I do not know Javascript well enough to write something like this froms scratch.

Answer (score 0):

i think [Fancy Box Plugin](http://fancybox.net) can help you. Check it out.